# Sass Rails doesn't support map syntax (object variables)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm getting the following error when trying to use [Sass Maps](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Maps) (which look like object variables):

> ```
> Invalid CSS after "  primary": expected ")", was ": #3097D1,"
>   (in /Users/.../app/assets/stylesheets/new_design.scss:19)
> ```

I reproduced the error by using the following minimal example:

```
$theme-colors: (
  primary: #3097D1,
  secondary: black
);

@each $key, $val in $theme-colors {
  .foo.#{$key} {
    color: $val;
  }
}
```

Expected:

```
.foo.primary {
  color: #3097D1;
}

.foo.secondary {
  color: black;
}
```

But getting the error mentioned.

`sass-rails, ~> 5.0.0` seems to be installed according to the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 5.0.0'
```

I'd assume that loads one of the latest sass versions which should support object variables.

I have the feeling the current version I have is not recognizing this syntax.

How can I make sure I have the right sass version? Is there anything else I have to do to compile this syntax successfully?

---

`bundle show sass-rails` shows `5.0.6`, which seems recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as discussed in the comments there is a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804209/how-to-use-sass-map-get-with-sass-syntax) discussion about a similar issue with the `map` sass syntax

The discussion refers to [`Github Issue 1088`](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1088)

I quote

> There's a number of issues with the indented syntax, and Sass maintainers aren't going to fix them. :( They say, the .sass parser is weird and hard to refactor.
>
> I find Sass syntax to be quicker to type and easier to read. It is deprived of the visual noise:
>
> indented_vs_bracketed
>
> It's also much easier to do copy-pasting.
>
> So Sass maintainers, PLEASE don't let the indented syntax fall behind!

Probably by digging down in the discussion we will be able to find the solution. Now I am quoting the solution from the owner of the post [Ionică Bizău](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/ionic%C4%83-biz%C4%83u):

> wrapping the values between quotes, saving, reloading in browser without any errors, and then removing the quotes back and reloading the page in browser solved the problem. Maybe it was something cached somewhere... but I can't understand where. I didn't restart rake or ran any bundle command... Thanks! :)

Comment: From the same page: [`Maps`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Maps).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get your suggestion. I have `sass-rails 5.0.6` installed, and `new_design.scss` is the manifest file itself.

Comment: @IonicăBizău don't know if this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804209/how-to-use-sass-map-get-with-sass-syntax I don't think that you need to use strings. also I checked all their issues. they don't have anything relative to this problem, so I really think that you should open an issue on github https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen&utf8=%E2%9C%93 It seems to me as being some sort of bug

Comment: @IonicăBizău like the only issue which is similar to yours is https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/333 but still something different. I believe you can get some help on their github page. sorry

Comment: Weird! Just by wrapping the values between quotes, saving, reloading in browser without any errors, and then removing the quotes back and reloading the page in browser solved the problem. Maybe it was something cached somewhere... but I can't understand where. I didn't restart `rake` or ran any `bundle` command... Thanks! :)

Comment: Hello @IonicăBizău . I don't think that I really helped you in finding the solution. I believe you are experienced to the point that you'll find the solution to anything, so I'll update my answer so that it is clear and then follow your blog. Thanks